# Eclipse-Plugin: Separator Line between FieldEditor possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, preferences

When you set up an eclipse plugin preference page, is it possible to add some sort of text or a separator line between the FieldEditors?

```
@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
    addField( new SomeFieldEditor(....));
    addField( new SomeFieldEditor(....));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
  Label label = new Label(getFieldEditorParent(), SWT.NONE);

  label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, false, 3, 1));
```

to add a blank like, or

```
  Label label = new Label(getFieldEditorParent(), SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);

  label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 3, 1));
```

to add a horizontal separator.

This assumes you are using the `GRID` layout. You might have to adjust the '3' in the `GridData` depending on how many columns the field editor end up using.